# iOS / Android - Can you read/write to Data Link layer on the mobile OS?

Tags: android, ios, sockets, networking

We are looking at using the Data Link-layer for a mobile app service for very low-latency requirements. We know that Mac OSX works on this level and from all our research it seems that you have to have rooted your phone (same goes for Android). Any information on whether we've just not found the right hook yet would be wonderful.

Answer (score 0):

So did you eventually succeed in having datalink sockets in android?